# Wamp stopped working after vmware installation.

Tags: php, wamp, vmware, wampserver

I have wamp running fine with 2 virtual hosts. But after installation of vmaware wamp server not starting. Any idea about this problem? Or how can i figure what make wamp not starting, does it store its error log somewhere?

I am using widows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that WMWare uses the same port as WAMP. I remember Skype doing this resulting in APACHE being unable to start the servers on its port.

You can use this tutorial to try and change the vSphere port from it's 80 default:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021199

LE: There could be some other WMWare component that uses the 80 port. Try closing all WMWare components and start WAMP. If it works, then WMWare is using the 80 port.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the 2 fight over the same port (80). Also, *Skype* might cause *WAMP* to fail at starting and to display "304" errors for every GET request on the server.

Change *WAMP*'s listening port from `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\conf`. Locate `httpd.conf`, open it with a text editor and search for listening. Change to whatever port you consider.